# Unknown column 'tasks_categories_ent.tce_сid' in 'on clause' MySQL

Tags: sql, join, объединение, inner

Объединяю через INNER JOIN:

```
INNER JOIN `tasks` ON users.vk_id = tasks.tvk_id LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks_categories_ent ON tasks_categories_ent.tce_eid = tasks.tid LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks_categories ON tasks_categories.tc_id = tasks_categories_ent.tce_сid
```

После того, как добавил:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks_categories ON tasks_categories.tc_id = tasks_categories_ent.tce_сid
```

получаю ошибку **Unknown column 'tasks_categories_ent.tce_сid' in 'on clause'**

Как исправить?

Comment: Структуру БД в студию)

Comment: @mctrane,

>>tasks - http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1364482491-clip-52kb.png
>>tasks_categories - http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1364482446-clip-3kb.png
>>tasks_categories_ent - http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1364482346-clip-5kb.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подозрительная буква `с` в tce_сid. Уж не русская ли там буква?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, ужс. И как так получилось :o Оформите как "ответ", Вы помогли очень!

Answer (score 0):

Может нужно написать так

```
tasks_categories_ent.tce_eid
```

???

Comment: @msi, неа :(

Comment: Вроде как удалял сообщение, когда увидел схему, но оно почему-то не удалилось. :-)

Comment: @msi, походу при соединении tasks_categories_ent.tce_сid не входит куда нужно и поэтому такая беда. Не знаю даже...

Comment: Я бы попробовал соединить только 2 последние таблицы. Не будет ли ошибки?

Comment: @msi, при двух не возникает. Даже при трёх не возникает. При четвёртой проблемы.

Comment: Т.е. соединяя их в любом порядке вы на четвертом соединении получаете ошибку?